# method calls itself when I instantiate the class

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have basic skills of OOP programming and I am trying to create a very simple MVC framework. Strangely the index method calls itself when I instantiate the app and couldn't figure out the reason.

My index file have this : $app = new App();

My bootstrap looks like this:

```
class App {

   private $_controller = null;

   public function __construct() {
       $default_controller = 'controller/index.php';
       require $default_controller;
       $this->_controller = new Index();
   }
}
```

Here is my main Controller class:

```
class Controller {

    public function loadModel($name) {
        require('models/'. strtolower($name) .'.php');

        $model = new $name;
        return $model;
    }

    public function loadView($name) {
        $view = new View($name);
        return $view;
    }
}
```

My main Model class:

```
class Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new DB(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);
    }

}
```

And here is my index class:

```
class Index extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $example = $this->loadModel('Index_Model');
        $something = $example->content('test');

        $view = $this->loadView('index');
        $view->set('content', $something);
        $view->render();
    }

}
```

Comment: In PHP 4, a method of the same name as the class served as the constructor - and it is still used as a compatibility fallback. (Case-insensitivity in certain aspects comes on top here.)

Comment: so do you mean if the class and its method have same name the method will be called when I instantiate the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Index extends Controller {

    public function index() {
```

In PHP 4, a method of the same name as the class served as the constructor - and it is still used as a compatibility fallback.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php:

> "For backwards compatibility with PHP 3 and 4, if PHP cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class."

(Case-insensitivity of PHP in certain aspects comes on top here.)

> [from comments] so do you mean if the class and its method have same name the method will be called when I instantiate the class?

Yes.

You will either have to rename the method, or provide a constructor via a method of the name __construct either in the class itself, or the one it extends.

---

Edit:
As you are diving into MVC as you said, you might want to look into namespaces. As the manual page I linked to further says, *"As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor."* - so that would eliminate the problem as well. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Comment: But I have running PHP version 5.6.10 on my local server?

Comment: Yeah that's the point. It's a backwards compatibility "feature"

Comment: As I said, it is a compatibility fallback - PHP 5 emulates the old behavior, so that scripts written under PHP 4 or 3 still can run without modification in this regard.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Namespaced classes do not have that problem since PHP 5.3.3, so you might want to look into those perhaps (see edit.)

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out even it looks a bit confusing for me :)

Comment: Don't worry, you don't have to make use of them right away, I mentioned it rather for completeness sake in the scope of the question/problem. They are foremost a means of organizing code in larger environments, where you deal with contributions from/modules written by different parties, etc. But you can easily put them on the stuff to read up on later pile for now ;-)